# How to remove unused imports from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is there any way to automatically remove all unused imports (signaled with a warning) of a project with Eclipse IDE?

Comment: @Dibya: Please do not randomly add language tags to questions that are _not_ about a language. Thank you.

Comment: The answers seem to mention Java; I was looking for this for C++. Does this work the same on a C++ project in Eclipse?

Comment: @dwanderson: sorry I used Eclipse mostly with Java. I don't think this works with C++.

Comment: @Heisenbug: Would you consider adding Java tag?

Comment: @NewUser: if it's Java only (probably it is), yes I (or you) can edit and fix the missing tag!

Comment: @Heisenbug: I did add the Java tag :) `Please do not randomly add language tags to questions that are not about a language. ` was intended to me! :)

Answer (score 269, accepted):

I just found the way. Right click on the desired package then `Source` -> `Organize Imports`.

Shortcut keys:

- Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>
- Mac: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

Comment: it's also quite helpful do define a save-action for this. Preferences->Java->Editor->Save Actions

Comment: Note that this will also 'clean' them up by moving them around to a more presentable manner.

Comment: How about `Android Studio`?

Comment: funny enough i had the situation where the import list contains an public static inner class from the same file and the 'organize imports' could not remove the unnecessary entry. As the class wasn't used i made it private and the organizer was successfull...

Answer (score 73):

You can direct use the shortcut by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

Comment: @minil if you mark the project/package in the Package explorer and then do Ctrl+Shift+O the whole project/package wil be cleaned of unused imports

Answer (score 49):

I know this is a very old thread. I found this way very helpful for me:

1. Go to Window → Preferences → Java → Editor → Save Actions.
2. Check the option "Perform the selected actions on save".
3. Check the option "Organize imports".

Now every time you save your classes, eclipse will take care of removing the unused imports.

Answer (score 12):

Remove all unused import in eclipse:

Right click on the desired package then **Source->Organize Imports.**
Or
You can direct use the shortcut by pressing **Ctrl+Shift+O**

Work perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to do this on whole project then inside project -->select src folder-->press **Ctrl+Shift+O**

Answer (score 7):

Use ALT + CTRL + O. It will organize all the imports. You can find various other options in the "Code" Menu.

EDIT: Sorry it is CTRL + SHIFT + O

Comment: I think it will be cntrl + shift + O

Answer (score 4):

press **Ctrl+Shift+O** and it will remove unwanted imports

Comment: This seems to be just a repeat of many of the existing answers.

Comment: Good, Straight forward Answer to comment out unnecessary import statements in `Eclipse`

Answer (score 3):

Better way is just to add "save action" so when you save the project it will clear the unused import's and format the code as well if you like .

Go to Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Save Actions

and pick what ever you want .

Answer (score 0):

Certainly in Eclipse indigo, a yellow line  appears under unused imports. If you hover over that, there will be multiple links; one of which will say "Remove unused import". Click that.

If you have multiple unused imports, just hover over one and there will be a link that allows  you to remove all unused imports at once. I can't remember the exact wording off hand, but all the links that appear are pretty self explanatory.

Comment: This applies to a single file only, not to a whole project.

Answer (score 0):

Not to reorganize imports (not to unfold .* and not to reorder lines) to have least VCS changeset
you can use custom eclipse clenup as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36453990/448078) suggests