# Remove unused import from All projects in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import, refactoring

Is there a way , a shortcut or any setting which removes unused import from **all projects** ? **effectively from workspace?**

I found following question  which states about removing from single file. [How to remove unused imports from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686825/remove-unused-import-from-eclipse).

But I need from whole workspace?

P.S.: Let me know if there are in any case ,a plug ins available for performing same.

Comment: Dont u hv ever use project explorer and then select the project and go to source and it has an option organize import ctr+shift+o ?

Comment: Also remember that you can add this as an save action. Then this will be performed everytime you save a file. Search for "save action" in preferences.

Comment: @Fredrik : yeah I am already using it as a save action.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Key combination `Ctrl+ Shift + O` - will trigger the `Organize Imports` that will remove and add missing imports.

To apply it on whole workspace you just have to select the project in the view `Package Explorer` and then use the key combination

Comment: It is for single file only.

Comment: It can be applied to entire projects too, or you can right click on a project and select it from the 'Source' menu.

Comment: @PriyankDoshi, This works on selected item view. If it is editor then it is single class if it is Package Explorer then it work on selected items.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks.it worked in Java perspective. but, not in Java EE perspective :(

Comment: @Keerthivasan: yes. But in Java EE, it is `Project Explorer` not `Package Explorer` :)

Comment: Actually only works for me when selecting all packages within project.  Selecting project itself does not work, ecl oxygen

Answer (score 6):

Right click your working set node, or all projects that you need and select Source->Organize Imports.

Shortcut is Ctrl+Shift+O, it is basically written in the menu so if you are using a different OS, you should be able to find it. It works on single files as well as project nodes in the Package Explorer

Answer (score 6):

As said, `Ctrl+ Shift + O` to do it manually or Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Save Actions -> Organize Imports to have it organized automatically whenever you save a class.

Comment: in MAC, its Eclipse -> Preferences

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Workspace -> Java Resources -> right click on (src/main/java) folder -> Select Sorce from the menu -> Now finally select Organize import & you are done.

Answer (score 0):

For macOS , you can use -->control+option+O combination.