# How to remove unused imports using Eclipse and not reorganize it?

Tags: java, eclipse

Organize imports (`<Ctrl>+<Shift>+O`) is well known feature of Eclipse.
How could I remove only unused imports, but not reorganize it (not unfold .* and not change line ordering)?

Comment: You may have more fine-grained control with the "Save Actions" :  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293475/organize-imports-automatically (also, you may add the additional action "Remove unused imports") .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try menu Source / Clean Up / Use custom profile and configure it to only do the "Remove unused imports".

Answer (score 1):

You can do it very easily upon saving a Java file by:

`Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Save Actions -> Check Additional Actions -> Configure -> Unnecessary Code -> Check on Remove Unused Imports`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply delete the lines with the yellow squiggle underline.

Comment: If the OP gets the yellow underline, meaning that he/she has the corresponding warning enabled, then another option is to just hover on such lines with the mouse and click "Removed unused imports" in the tooltip that will pop up.

Answer (score 0):

As I know it is not possible automatically do.

You can repeat this steps

1. `Ctrl + .` (This will move cursor to the next error or warning
2. `Ctrl + 1` - show hints
3. Remove unused import