# How do you detect useless imports? When do you import a library when using multiple sheets and functions?

Tags: python, excel, function, class, import

**Question 1:**
Lets say this is the start of my code.

Obviously there are functions from libraries that are being imported twice.

But also what if I never use os.path in this program.

Is there any way to check if these libraries aren't being used?

**Code:**

```
import xlwt
import xlrd
import xlutils.copy
import xlutils
import copy
import os.path
import csv
import pyexcel
import sys
import time
import subprocess


from xlutils.copy import copy
from xlrd         import open_workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy as xl_copy
```

**Question 2:** If I have two python files: one where I define the class excelFunctions and the other where I call upon the function getSheetNumber.

This uses xlrd for reading the excel sheet. On which sheet do I import xlrd?

**Code:**

```
class excelFunctions():

    def getSheetNumber(self, fileName, sheetName):

        # opens existing workbook
        workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(fileName, on_demand=True)

        #turns sheet name into sheet number       
        for index, sheet in enumerate(workbook.sheet_names()):
            if sheet == sheetName:
                return index
```

Comment: For question 1, get an IDE. There's not really a way for Python to tell which imports are used, because it could change at runtime in theory. For 2, you have to import a module in every file you want to use it in. If you define a function in file 1, the import needs to be in file 1, You don't, however, need to import the module that the function depends on in file 2, just the module that has the function.

Comment: Imports happen once.  If python sees an import statement for something it has already imported, it doesn't re-import

Comment: I don't think you can really check if a library is used or not. Take the following example: `exec(input())` (don't do that actually). Does it use a library or not? You can't know. Of course this is a kinda articifical example. Normally IDEs should do that for you, grepping through the source code might be enough.

Comment: I use eclipse. How do I use eclipse to detect libraries that aren't being used

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. And contrary to previous comments, a good linter like PyFlakes or PyLint is perfectly capable of detecting unused imports.

Comment: @nickm From googling exactly that, it looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686825/how-to-remove-unused-imports-from-eclipse

Comment: If you are using Eclipse (Pydev), go to `preferences>Pydev>Editor>Code Analsis` and choose the `pep8.py` tab and put the option on `Warning`. Then you will see a yellow warning beside unused imports.