# How to Remove Unused Objects in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I'm working on a project for several years now and I found that I declare thousands of objects in various classes that are never used locally such as:

```
public class MyClass {


 ClassA classA = new ClassA();
 ClassB classB = new ClassB();
 ClassC classC = new ClassC();


 public void performAction()
 {
 classA.doA();
 }


}
```

While I use instance of `classA` in `MyClass` I never use `classB` and `classC` locally (they're used in other classes of course). Of course, this is just one example. My project has several thousand instances of classes (spread across hundreds of classes) that are never used. Apparently, I thought I'd actually need access to the methods in `classB` and `classC` but never actually did and I'm left with thousands of unnecessary object instantiations. I believe this is causing a significant increase in memory utilization (correct?).

Is there a way to automatically detect instances of unused classes and delete them in Eclipse? I know there's a way to [delete unused imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686825/how-to-remove-unused-imports-from-eclipse) but I could not find anything on SO about unused objects.

I'm using Eclipse Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)

Thanks!

Comment: use `SonarLint`plugin to help you clean up your code.

Comment: Eclipse can detect unused private elements and shows warnings. Maybe that can help a bit.